# gtk-handle events from a list store treeview

Tags: c, linux, gtk

my code is as follows

```
   #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #include <glib.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    GtkWidget *scrolledwindow;

    struct param
{
    GtkWidget*parent;
    GtkWidget*newChild;
};
GtkWidget * init_tree();
GtkWidget * init_tree2();
static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->parent), (GtkWidget*)tree_view);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->parent), init_tree2()/*parameters->newChild*/);
}


    GtkWidget * init_tree()
    {

        GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
        GtkTreeIter treeiter;

        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
     GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

        GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

        GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                     cellrenderertext,
                                                                                     "text", 0,
                                                                                     NULL);
        gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

        return treeview;
    }

    GtkWidget * init_tree2()
    {

        GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
        GtkTreeIter treeiter;

        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "a", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "b", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "c", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "d", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "e", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "f", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
     gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
        gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
        gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

        GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

        GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

        GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                     cellrenderertext,
                                                                                     "text", 0,
                                                                                     NULL);
        gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

        return treeview;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

      GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
      gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
      g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

      GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


      int count;
      gchar *text;

      for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
        {
          GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
          text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);
          GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

          gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolledwindow, -1, 200);

          gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), scrolledwindow);
          GtkWidget *textview = gtk_text_view_new();
          /* gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), textview); */
          GtkWidget* treeview = init_tree();
          GtkWidget* treeview2 = init_tree2();
struct param* parameters = malloc(sizeof(struct param));
      parameters->parent = scrolledwindow;
      parameters->newChild= treeview2;
          g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab),(gpointer)parameters);
          gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), treeview);

          gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
        }

      gtk_widget_show_all(window);

      gtk_main();

      return 0;
    }
```

I have 2 liststore instances treview1 and treeview2.
1st- treeview 1 is displayed. On double clicking any liststore item, it generates "row-activated " signal. this signal is linked with function "replace_tab" with G_CALLBACK. 
func "replace_tab " takes 4 parameters- parent Widget, Widget to remove from parent , widget to add to parent and gpointer data. How to pass arguments to this func. Or is there any other method for the solution.

Comment: Your callback must match the prototype defined for ["row_activated" signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated). The parameters are provided by GTK on calling your callback. BTW: You create both treeviews 5 times in your loop.

Comment: the prototype is void
user_function (GtkTreeView       *tree_view,
               GtkTreePath       *path,
               GtkTreeViewColumn *column,
               gpointer           user_data)                                                                                                 Then how to pass parent Widget and next child widget to this function?

Comment: You can pass whatever parameter you want via the `user_data` pointer during `g_signal_connect`. You can create a struct variable and pass a pointer to it.

Comment: You might need one instance of this variable for each instance of your treeview.

Comment: I have changed code. passed parent and new child widgets as parameters in parameters argument of type gpointer. But still the new liststore does not appear on double clicking element of previous liststore

Comment: How many times do you want to create treeview2? Where do you put your `parameters` structure? You should get seg fault on accessing NULL pointer.

Comment: that was editing mistake.I have put the right parameter now.for treeview2, I tried with the instance passed by gpointer. Since it did not do the job, I created a new treeview2. I will keep one instance only in the final output. But it is now not working. Showing blank screen with double clicking liststore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The code is not good but that is not the question**, so, to solve the specific problem of not showing the second treeview instead of the first on double click:

1. as @Gerhardh said, you need to pass the parameters to the callback as the last argument, otherwise the application will segfault on double clicking a row: `g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), parameters);`
2. You must show the new treeview, in the `replace_tab` function: `gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->parent));`

Your code with the above suggestions:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
GtkWidget * init_tree();
GtkWidget * init_tree2();
GtkWidget *scrolledwindow;
struct param
{
    GtkWidget*parent;
    GtkWidget*newChild;
};

static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
   gtk_main_quit();
}

static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
   struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
   gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->parent), (GtkWidget*)tree_view);
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->parent), init_tree2()/*parameters->newChild*/);
   gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->parent));
}


GtkWidget * init_tree()
{
  GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
  GtkTreeIter treeiter;

  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
  gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
  gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

  GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

  GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

  GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                               cellrenderertext,
                                                                               "text", 0,
                                                                               NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

  return treeview;
}

GtkWidget * init_tree2()
{

   GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
   GtkTreeIter treeiter;

   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "a", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "b", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "c", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "d", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "e", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "f", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);

   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
   gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

   GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

   GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

   GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                               cellrenderertext,
                                                                               "text", 0,
                                                                               NULL);
   gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

   return treeview;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
   g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

   GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


   int count;
   gchar *text;

   for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
   {
      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);
      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

      gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolledwindow, -1, 200);

      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), scrolledwindow);
      GtkWidget* treeview = init_tree();
      GtkWidget* treeview2 = init_tree2();
      struct param* parameters = malloc(sizeof(struct param));
      parameters->parent = scrolledwindow;
      parameters->newChild= treeview2;
      g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), parameters);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), treeview);

      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
   }

   gtk_widget_show_all(window);

   gtk_main();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: one more thing I need-the treeview2 consumes the entire page. I want there should be another back button at bottom left corner. Clicking back shows the 1st treeview.

Comment: @SagarMohantu, if you want to switch between two versions, maybe just hinding a widget instead of removing it might be an option.

Comment: can you look at the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399178/gtk-back-button-does-not-remove-from-grid-liststore-treeview-row-is-not-shown-fu

Comment: thanks it works. Sorry but I do not understand what do you mean by accepting answers. I accept your answers.