# gtk-back button does not remove from grid, liststore treeview row is not shown full

Tags: c, linux, list, gtk

I have 2 concerns:

1. in a page when I click the list item another list with a button is added to grid, but when I press button, the 1st page comes back, but the back button is not removed from grid.
2. list store items are not shown in full, it is truncated.

How do I show the full list?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
GtkWidget *scrolledwindow;
struct param
{
    GtkWidget* grid;
    GtkWidget* scrolledwindow;
    GtkWidget*newChild;
    GtkWidget*oldChild;
};
GtkWidget * init_tree();
GtkWidget * init_tree2();
static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

static void Back (GtkButton *button, gpointer   user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->oldChild);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->newChild);
      gtk_grid_remove_row (GTK_GRID (parameters->grid),20);
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->grid));


}


static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      //gtk_grid_insert_row ( GTK_GRID(grid),2);
      gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), GTK_WIDGET(tree_view));
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->newChild);
      GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Back");
      gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (parameters->grid), button, 0, 20, 2, 2);
      parameters->oldChild = parameters->newChild;
      parameters->newChild= init_tree();
      g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (Back), parameters);
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->grid));
}

GtkWidget * init_tree()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
 GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

GtkWidget * init_tree2()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "a", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "b", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "c", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "d", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "e", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "f", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);

gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

 GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


  int count;
  gchar *text;

  for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
    {
      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);
      GtkWidget* grid = gtk_grid_new ();
      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

      gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolledwindow, -1, 200);

      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), grid/*scrolledwindow*/);

      //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(grid), scrolledwindow);
      gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), scrolledwindow, 0, 0, 200, 10);
      //GtkWidget *textview = gtk_text_view_new();
      /* gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), textview); */
      GtkWidget* treeview = init_tree();
      GtkWidget* treeview2 = init_tree2();
      struct param* parameters = malloc(sizeof(struct param));
      parameters->scrolledwindow = scrolledwindow;
      parameters->grid = grid;
      parameters->newChild= treeview2;
      g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), (gpointer)parameters);
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), treeview);

      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
    }

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, ask just one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, the code is not good but that is not the question**, so, to solve the specific problem of implementing a back button while showing a second `treeview` inside the same notebook page you can reuse the `vbox` that contains the `treeview` and add a button below it. You must set the `no-show-all` property to true and set the show/hide status by yourself. Basically, you want to show it only while showing the second `treeview`.

I've used `GtkBox` pack functions and within the callbacks, show and hide the back button.

Try your code with these minor tweaks:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
GtkWidget *scrolledwindow;
struct param
{
    GtkWidget* backbutton;
    GtkWidget* scrolledwindow;
    GtkWidget*newChild;
    GtkWidget*oldChild;
};
GtkWidget * init_tree();
GtkWidget * init_tree2();
static void destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

static void Back (GtkButton *button, gpointer   user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
      gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), GTK_WIDGET(parameters->newChild));
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->oldChild);
      gtk_widget_hide (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->backbutton));
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
}


static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
      struct param* parameters = (struct param*)user_data;
      gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
      gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), GTK_WIDGET(tree_view));
      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parameters->scrolledwindow), parameters->newChild);
      gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->backbutton));
      gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET(parameters->scrolledwindow));
}

GtkWidget * init_tree()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Mandriva", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);
    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

GtkWidget * init_tree2()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "a", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "b", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "c", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "d", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "e", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "f", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Aptosid", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "OpenSuSE", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Linux Mint", -1);

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Arch Linux", -1);

    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Distributions",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), notebook);


  int count;
  gchar *text;

  for (count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
    {
      text = g_strdup_printf("Page %d", count);
      GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(text);

      GtkWidget *vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
      GtkWidget *scrolledwindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

      GtkWidget *backbutton = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Back");
      gtk_widget_set_no_show_all (backbutton, TRUE);

      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(vbox), scrolledwindow, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX(vbox), backbutton, FALSE, FALSE, 0);


      GtkWidget* treeview = init_tree();
      GtkWidget* treeview2 = init_tree2();
      struct param* parameters = malloc(sizeof(struct param));
      parameters->backbutton = backbutton;
      parameters->scrolledwindow = scrolledwindow;
      parameters->oldChild= treeview;
      parameters->newChild= treeview2;

      g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), (gpointer) parameters);
      g_signal_connect(backbutton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Back), (gpointer) parameters);

      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledwindow), treeview);
      gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook), vbox, label);
    }

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Your Widget packaging its not good. I would suggest you try [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) and use it as a playground to learn about widget placement.

Also learn about [GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html) which would fit this purpose much better and even add "cool" animated transitions.

Comment: can u answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420575/gtk-get-which-item-is-clicked-in-the-liststore-treeview