# gtk-get which item is clicked in the liststore treeview

Tags: c, linux, list, treeview, gtk

I want to get the item that is clicked in the treeview which causes "row-activated" event. I have a list store in a treeview. Clicking any item of it shows another list. But how do I know which item is clicked?
How do I find that?
code-

```
GtkWidget * init_tree()
{

    GtkListStore *liststore = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeIter treeiter;

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Register", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "New Configuration", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Edit Configuration", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Delete Configuration", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Add location to turn-off place list", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Disable Turn-off Places", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Enable Turn-off Places", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Disable Distance", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Enable Distance", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &treeiter, 0, "Factory Reset", -1);
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &treeiter);
    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(liststore));

    GtkCellRenderer *cellrenderertext = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *treeviewcolumn = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Settings",
                                                                                 cellrenderertext,
                                                                                 "text", 0,
                                                                                 NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), treeviewcolumn);

    return treeview;
}

static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
..........
}

int main(...)
{
....
g_signal_connect(treeview, "row-activated", G_CALLBACK(replace_tab), (gpointer) parameters);

.....
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common ways to get the `treeview` selection on double click (`row-activated`) are:

**1. Using variables from the `row-activated` callback**

The signal handler from `row-activated` signal is:

> ```
> void
> user_function (GtkTreeView       *tree_view,
>                GtkTreePath       *path,
>                GtkTreeViewColumn *column,
>                gpointer           user_data)
> ```

We can retrieve data from the model with the exposed variables; from the `GtkTreePath path` we get the `GtkTreeIter iter` and from the `GtkTreeView treeview` we can get the `GtkTreeModel model`. Having the `model` and the `iter` we can retrieve data from the `model`; eg. in your `replace_tab` signal handler, add the following:

```
static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{
   gchar *string;
   GtkTreeIter iter;
   GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (tree_view);
   gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &iter, path); 
   gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, 0, &string, -1);
   g_print ("activated: %s\n", string);
   ...

 }
```

This should print the text from the activated row

**2. Using GtkTreeSelection**

Another option is to use `GtkTreeSelection` which we can retrieve from the `GtkTreeView` itself. This step allow us to extract the selected `iter` (single selection on the tree view) with which we will get the data from the `model`; eg in your `replace_tab` signal handler, add the following:

```
static void replace_tab(GtkTreeView *tree_view, GtkTreePath *path, GtkTreeViewColumn *column, gpointer user_data)
{ 
   gchar *string;
   GtkTreeIter iter;
   GtkTreeSelection *selection;
   GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (tree_view);

   selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection (tree_view);
   gtk_tree_selection_get_selected (selection, &model, &iter); 
   gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, 0, &string, -1);
   g_print ("activated: %s\n", string);
   ...
}
```

**Conclusion:**

Option 1) it's easier, cleaner and straight forward. Normally 2) it's used to get selection changes via the `changed` signal emitted by `GtkTreeSelection`.